# How to send multipart file upload straight to mongodb in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, formidable

I can save the file to disk with formidable and then send the file bits to mongo with node, but how can I just handle streaming the file bits directly to mongo?

I don't need gridfs, these are small files.  Just want to write them to the normal store.

Answer (score 1):

Use options.fileWriteStreamHandler to setup your own stream. Then write to mongodb if the API accepts a stream